# Where are replicas stored in the Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, replication

I'm trying to verify that "unregistering" a replica from the Manage replicas dialog does, in fact, *delete* the replica.

I looked for a table pertaining to replicas, but all I see is `GDB_REPLICALOG`.  I was expecting some table with one row for each replica.

What table in the geodatabase is used to create the list shown in this dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is GDB_ITEMS. Look for records in this table with a type of 4ED4A58E-621F-4043-95ED-850FBA45FCBC

Comment: Thanks! It is nice to see that the password to the other database that gets stored there is encrypted.